# What is an equivalent Portuguese expression for "to bite off more than one can chew"?

Tags: expressões, tradução

What is an equivalent Portuguese expression for "to bite off more than one can chew," that is, to take on a task that is too complex, costly, or lengthy to be completed? ([reference](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bite_off_more_than_one_can_chew))

Example: *He bit off more than he could chew when he bought that 1880s-era house.*

Is there a similar expression in Portuguese?

Comment: I only remember a expression similar to this one, but in the sense of food. "Comer com a boca maior que o estômago", that is "to eat with the mouth bigger than the stomach", that means to eat more than one can bear.

Comment: @BrunoLopes That sounds like an equivalent of "his eyes are bigger than his stomach."

Comment: Yeah, that's another variation of this expression.

Comment: There's also *muita areia para o [meu|seu|etc] caminhãozinho*.

Comment: @bfavaretto Ou em Portugal *muita areia para a [minha|tua|etc] camioneta*.

Comment: "tens mais olhos que barriga." -> "your eyes are bigger than your stomach."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the nearest in meaning would be "dar o passo maior que a perna" (i.e. "try to jump more than your legs could").

Comment: *He bit off more than he could chew when he bought that 1880s-era house.* -> "Ele deu o passo maior que a perna quando comprou esta casa da era de 1880."

Comment: Ótima tradução, deve funcionar na maior parte dos casos.

Answer (score 6):

Based on this context:

> *I think **I bit off more than I could chew** when I agreed to paint
>   this house by myself*.

the Portuguese expression for this would be:

> **Ter mais olhos que barriga** - Eu tive mais olhos que barriga quando aceitei pintar esta casa toda sozinho.

When a person accepts a lot of work and then can't handle it.
Another example - at the table when a person serves to much food and then can't eat it all.

### Tem mais olhos que barriga

Comment: The problem of that expression is that it's usually linked to a greedy behaviour. Biting off more than one can chew may simply be caused by a placebo, increased expectations, or a lack of measurement.

Comment: No Brasil a expressão é ligeiramente diferente, "ter o olho maior que a barriga".